# Restoring Windows registry not deleting new values

Tags: windows, mobile, registry

We can create windows registry backup to .reg file. And then we can restore registry from this file.

Lets assume that after backup creation some new keys were added to registry. During restoring backup this new keys will not be deleted (because restoring only writes/changes keys) and in fact the restore will not be correct. Am I right?

I am facing the same problem. I have created program (for windows ce) working that way. It saves all registry keys and values to some file and also allows to write all this keys and values back to registry.
During restoring I can check if there were added new values in **some key** and I can delete them eventually. But I can't check if there were added new subkeys in **some key**, because I would have to analyse the whole backup file checking if there is or there is not this subkey in backup. This analyse would be very time consuming, especially on mobile device.

Is it possible and safe to delete all registry keys and restore them right after deletion? Have you some clue about that?

Comment: I'm not sure why checking for added subkeys would be all that more time-consuming than restoring in the first place.

Comment: To do that I would have to create a **list of keys** from current registry and during writing old values I would have to check if old key exists in this **list of keys**. If there is no other solution I would have to to this, but definitely it is more time consuming than all registry key deletion.

Comment: It's much more time-consuming to write the code, but not much to execute it.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your idea of less time-consuming solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, since my comparisons were all on the basis of whether or not to include the feature of deleting added subkeys by comparing them, and the cost relative to the naive algorithm. There is no "less time-consuming solution"; I'm just saying that your estimate of the runtimes involved is a lot more pessimistic than is warranted. Premature optimization is a root of all kinds of evil, so try it and see if it's fast enough.